# Getting subtypes from standalone table in ArcObjects

Tags: arcobjects, table, subtype

I have been working in the next code to get all Subtypes from a standalone table in a single string that concatenates it. 
I work with ArcMap and arcobjects library in C# (sharp) language.

But I can not put it to works it correctly.

My actual code:

```c#
IDocument docRDC = m_application.Document;
IMxDocument mxdocRDC = docRDC as IMxDocument;

string esFeature = "";
string esTable = "";

if (mxdocRDC.SelectedItem is IFeatureLayer2)
    {
    esFeature = "Si";
    MessageBox.Show("Es IFeaturelayer2");
    }

if (mxdocRDC.SelectedItem is ITable)
    {
    esTable = "Si";
    MessageBox.Show("Es Itable");
    }

ITable table = mxdocRDC.SelectedItem as ITable;

System.Text.StringBuilder listadosubtipos = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

if (esFeature != "Si" && esTable=="Si")
            {
                IObjectClass MiObjeClassTabla = table as IObjectClass;
                ISubtypes MisSubtypesTabla = (ISubtypes)MiObjeClassTabla;
                IEnumSubtype enumSubtypeTabla;
                int subtypeCodeTabla;
                string subtypeNameTabla;


            if (MisSubtypesTabla.HasSubtype)
                {
                enumSubtypeTabla = MisSubtypesTabla.Subtypes;
                subtypeNameTabla = enumSubtypeTabla.Next(out subtypeCodeTabla);

                while (subtypeNameTabla != null)
                    {
                    listadosubtipos.Append(subtypeNameTabla);
                    listadosubtipos.Append(", ");
                    subtypeNameTabla = enumSubtypeTabla.Next(out subtypeCodeTabla);
                    }
                }

                textBox3.Text = Convert.ToString(listadosubtipos);
            }
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? Are the results not what you expect? What is the problem?

Comment: when I run the application; it just executes until they reach the row 25 (IObjectClass MiObjeClassTabla = table as IObjectClass;) and then nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

[IFeatureLayer](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//0012000004tp000000) does not implement [IObjectClass](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002500000606000000) but IFeatureLayer.FeatureClass does, which is why your cast to `IObjectClass MiObjeClassTabla` is Null. Likewise if your `mxdocRDC.SelectedItem` is a standalone table is likely to be of type [ITableView](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002900000079000000), from which you can access the underlying table using `(mxdocRDC.SelectedItem as ITableView).Table`.

I would suggest starting the code like this:

```c#
ITable table=null; // initialize the table to nothing 

if (mxdocRDC.SelectedItem is IFeatureLayer)
{
    esFeature = "Si";
    MessageBox.Show("Es IFeaturelayer2");
    // IFeatureClass implements ITable so a direct cast should be no problem
    table = (ITable) (mxdocRDC.SelectedItem as IFeatureLayer).FeatureClass; 
}

if (mxdocRDC.SelectedItem is ITableView)
{
    esTable = "Si";
    MessageBox.Show("Es Itable");
    table = (mxdocRDC.SelectedItem as ITableView).Table;
}

if (null != table)
{
    // do the rest of your code here because a valid datasource found
}
```

But beware, a layer or table view can be invalid, indicated by a red exclamation mark. For interfaces that implement [ILayer](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//0012000006z1000000) you can test that the layer.Valid before continuing, giving you a chance to exit gracefully before the program proceeds to crash and burn.